# Reading property names from a properties file before loading it (ANT)

Tags: ant, properties-file

I need to retrieve all the properties' names from a properties file before loading it (using Ant)

I'll go into detail to explain the whole process:

1. A first properties file (let's name it as a.properties) is read and
   all its properties loaded as project's properties.

   ```
   #a.properties's contents
   myvar1=1
   myvar2=someTextHere
   ```
2. A second file (let's say b.properties) has to be loaded on the
   project. Some already-set properties can also be contained in this
   second file, so what we have to do is to update such variables with
   the value found on it (by means of the `ant-contrib`'s `var` target)

   ```
   #b.properties's contents
   myvar1=2  #updated value for a property that's is already set on the project
   myvar3=1,2,3,4,5,6
   ```
3. So the expected subset (from a ANT project's properties perspective)
   of property/value pairs would be:

   ```
   myvar1=2
   myvar2=someTextHere
   myvar3=1,2,3,4,5,6
   ```

**We cannot change the order** in which those files are loaded on the project, which would be the easiest way of solving the issue (because of the behavior adopted by Ant when setting's properties)

Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please show the respective build script that you have.

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot change the order in which the properties files are loaded. You state that it's due Ant's property immutability, but you can simply use this to your advantage (this is a design feature of Ant, not a shortcoming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the approach I followed was to specify the second properties file (`b.properties`) from the command line:

```
ant <my_target> -propertyfile b.properties
```

So that's work fine to me...

Thanks all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to read properties from different files before you build your source code

```
<target name=-init-const-properties description="read all properties required">
  <propertyfile file="AbsolutePathToPropertyFile" comment="Write meaningfull 
    about the properties">
        <entry value="${myvar1}" key="VAR1"/>
        <entry value="${myvar2}" key="VAR2"/>
  </propertyfile>
</target>
```

Note: you need to add proper `AbsolutePathToPropertyFile`and comment if required

In the target `-init-const-properties` you can add as many files you want to read and use this target as dependent target in which you going to use these property values. hope this will answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a standard file for build defaults called "build.properties". If you need to override any settings, then create an optional file called "build-local.properties".

My advice is to keep build logic simple. Using the ant-contrib extension to make properties act like variables is rarely needed in my experience.

## Example

```
├── build-local.properties
├── build.properties
└── build.xml
```

Running the project produces the following output, where the value "two" is substituted:

```
$ ant
build:
     [echo] Testing one, dos, three
```

Delete the optional file and it goes back to default values:

```
$ rm build-local.properties
$ ant

build:
     [echo] Testing one, two, three
```

### build.xml

The secret is the order in which the property files are loaded. If they don't exist then they don't create properties.

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <property file="build-local.properties"/>
  <property file="build.properties"/>

  <target name="build">
    <echo message="hello ${myvar1}, ${myvar2}, ${myvar3}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

### build.properties

```
myvar1=one
myvar2=two
myvar3=three
```

### build-local.properties

```
myvar2=dos
```